# Powershell how to check if text content is not empty in xml object

Tags: xml, powershell

With an xml like this:

```
<parent>
   <child1>my value</child1>
   <child2></child2>
</parent>
```

I need to check if child nodes content is not empty.
This is my code:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content my.xml
$xml.SelectNodes('//parent/*') | ForEach-Object {        
    if ($_) {
        Write-Host $_.name
    }
}
```

The expected output is

```
child1
```

Instead I get both:

```
child1
child2
```

How should I change the if line ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using our example I would do like this (add .innerText to $_).

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content ".\my.xml"
$xml.SelectNodes('//parent/*') | ForEach-Object {        
    if ($_.innerText) {
        Write-Host $_.name
    }
}
```

But personally I would do it like this:

```
foreach ($child in $xml.Parent.GetEnumerator()) {
    if ($child.innerText) {
        "$($child.Name) = $($child.innerText)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$xml.SelectNodes('//parent/*')
```

to

```
$xml.SelectNodes('//parent/*[text()]')
```

and see if it works.